# PHP can I kill the script and have an alert?

Tags: javascript, php

I want it to kill the script then post an alert while staying on the same page

This is my code:

```
   if (empty($_POST['item'])) {
            print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            print 'alert("The item is required")'; 
            print '</script>';  
        }
```

The problem is it doesn't kill the script

Is there a way to make it so that it kill the script, does the prints, and stay on the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
void exit ([ string $status ] )
```

**or**

```
void exit ( int $status )
```

to terminate your current *php* script.

Comment: is there a way I can make it refresh the page?

Comment: @user3531211 : `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`.

Comment: for example <script> if (alert = true) { (refresh command here)}

Comment: Is $status a universal variable or do I put something there?

Comment: @user3531211 : `$status` is not required, it a string that is outputted when `exit()` is executed.

Comment: can I change the "OK" button on the alert to a "go back" button?

Comment: @user3531211 : No you can't , but you can create a  dialog using jQuery UI Dialog.